# Not able to drag and drop some component from palette in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

Not able to drag and drop some components from the palette in android studio.

Components like 'ImageView', 'ImageButton', 'ImageFilterView', 'ImageFilterButton', 'FloatingActionButton'
are not able to drag and drop from palette.

But I can able to drag and drop 'Button', 'TextView', 'ScrollView', 'Switch', 'ListView' and all from palette

[Video example of Problem,](https://capture.dropbox.com/dFua8jpCe9kWf4v0)